# C# selenium webdriver chrome driver wait until modal window is completely gone

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using the chrome driver with C# webdriver.  one of the problems i'm facing is waiting for "exist" or "visible" is not working in my case because the modal window takes some time to go away.  and i'm getting this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (x,x). Other element would receive the click:

reason being that the modal backdrop is still present for a few seconds after I click OK/Cancel, but the element behind the backdrop is visible and clickable to selenium.

so how do i "wait" until the modal backdrop is completely gone before attempting to click something behind it? this is not a native javascript modal.  it's a fancy third party modal that slides in and out of view with a transparent "cover" that prevents clicking on anything else when it's open.

Comment: have you tried `Thread.Sleep(...)` ?

Comment: post your code maybe it will help to answer you better

Comment: Selenium already has a built-in mechanic to force the browser to wait.  Check the documentation for it [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: Well what "third party tool"? Is it a jQuery plugin? Have you checked the dialog's `.Displayed` property?

Comment: @AbuHamzah I actually read somewhere here that using Thread.Sleep is bad practice.  I'm wondering why there is not a simple Pause() in webdriver for X seconds?

Comment: @Brian yes it has wait for certain conditions that I'm very familiar with.  but as I explained this case is different.  Waiting for Existence or Clickable in this case doesn't work because those return true, while in reality they are hidden behind a modal backdrop and not actually clickable.

Comment: The **is** a [pause](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause) in Selenium.

Comment: i'm using webdriver.  that's the old selenium that has pause.

Comment: i have been working with webdriver and i never had any success with Explicit and Implicit Waits

Comment: yes i know the thread.sleep is not a good one but its a hack and it works perfectly fine

Comment: ok, i've ended up going with a simple sleep for 300 ms and retry until the exception goes away.  works fine now.  this way at least it won't sleep unless it has to.

Answer (score 4):

You could user the ExpectedConditions API, such as:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("elementId")));
```

This will try during 1 minute until the element is clickable and is it does not happen it will throw an exception.